# Makefile: Storing the Argument that comes after 'make' (i.e the 2nd command line argument) isn't Working

Tags: if-statement, makefile, conditional-statements, command-line-arguments, gnu-make

I'm trying to store the 2nd argument passed in command line (i.e the argument after `make`) in a variable called `NAME`, and then use it to do stuff. If there is no 2nd argument then `NAME = a` .

Why doesn't it work?

Here is a snippet from my `Makefile`:

```
NAME := $(shell $2)

ifeq ($(strip $(NAME)),)
    $(NAME) = a
endif


# ... and do other things with NAME
```

It gives me this error:

```
*** empty variable name. Stop
```

Comment: The line `$(NAME) = a` is not right; you are trying to set the value that the `NAME` variable expands to, which is the empty string, which is why you get this message.  You want `NAME = a`.  Also note you should use `:=` when assigning from `shell`: it's more efficient: `NAME := $(shell ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `$1` (and similar) in `make`.

The parameters of `make` are targets or options and can't access with `$1`.

The command `make foo` instructs `make` to create `foo` target. If you want pass parameters you can use `make param=foo` and can access in `Makefile` the `${param}` variable (with value `foo`).

Comment: Not `$param`! This will probably expand as `aram` (or `whateveraram` if make variable `p` is defined and has value `whatever`). The make syntax is `$(param)` or `${param}`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @uzsolt heres another question tho... Is there a way to do what you said: 'make NAME=foo'...  but not just change NAME in this one instance but instead overwrite it in the file, and then just call 'make' directly with 'foo' already being assigned to NAME; and then everytime you would do 'make NAME=someName' it would overwrite it; basically allowing you to type 'make NAME=someName' once instead of every single time you want name to be 'someName'.

Comment: @notAymen You can define `NAME=foo` in your `Makefile` of course. The `make`-case: `NAME` is foo. The `make NAME=bar`-case: `NAME` is bar. So the commandline parameter overrides the declarations in the `Makefile`.